# Plotting Hours in X axis MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot `TP` vs `time`. I have the following data extracted from Excel:

```
y-axis    x axis
28.72   13:02:55.58
28.21   13:08:49.53
23.32   13:14:43.48
28.85   13:20:34.48
28.84   13:26:28.51
28.37   13:32:22.51
28.75   13:38:16.49
26.85   13:44:10.55
25.99   13:50:03.51
27.65   13:55:55.54
5.99    14:01:48.51
11.28   14:07:26.52
16.15   14:13:10.56
15.19   14:18:57.49
24.32   14:24:44.50
26.13   14:30:36.49
27.92   14:36:29.53
17.96   14:42:22.54
10.08   14:48:10.54
14.73   14:53:54.52
18.12   14:59:41.48
```

I have some `TP` in Mbps on the Y-axis and `time` in the HH:MM:SS format on the X-axis. How can I set the tick marks on the X-axis to use the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`datetick`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html)

```
datetick('x',HH:MM:SS) %// use required DateFormat, see docs
```

Comment: Is there a SS.ss ? Or is it just SS to represent the 4 digit second?

Comment: @GameOfThrows [The docs](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html#inputarg_dateFormat) only speak about 2 digit seconds. Might be they did not include it; try and see whether it works I'd say

Comment: yes, I was just wondering because the OP said "Y-axis and time in the HH:MM:SS" but the Data actually showed 2 digit second + 2 digit centi-second.

Comment: @GameOfThrows He has his time in that, but wants to plot it in "hours" according to his title. I suspect the centiseconds are only plotted for very small ranges e.g. [0 1]s, where you'd normally use the regular numbers anyway instead of `datetick`